# Como buscar la ruta de un archivo en windows con Python

Tags: python

Mi pregunta es, como puedo obtener la ruta de un programa en especifico en windows para este caso supongamos word que el ejecutable por default es **WINWORD.EXE**.

Pero apesar de que el ejecutable es el mismo en cualquier version,no es la misma ruta en cualquier maquina.

Entonces

¿Como podría obtener la ruta de en este caso de WINWORD.EXE

**Ejemplo:**
obetner los campos xxxxx, sin importar el pc 
    C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\WINWORD.EXE

**NOTA:**

Hace algun tiempo lei algo sobre os.walk() no se si esto se pueda implementar en este caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

Tienes que cambiar las variables dir_base por tu directorio base a partir de donde buscar. Supongo que `C:/` para tu caso. Y fichero requerido que sería `WINWORD.EXE`

```
import os

dir_base = '/usr/'
fichero_requerido = 'perl'

for root, folders, files in os.walk(dir_base):
    for file in files:
        if file == fichero_requerido:
            print('Encontrado '+file+' en '+os.path.join(root, file))
            break
```